# How do you evaluate $\int_0^\infty xf(x)\text{d}x$, where $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How do you evaluate $$\int_0^\infty xf(x)\text{d}x,$$ where $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$?

Edit:
[Here is my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9Sb.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: So you want to evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\text{d}x$?

Comment: It screams in integration by parts.

Comment: yea that would be the same thing

Comment: I did it with intergration by parts but I got stuck on it

Comment: Show us the work you did with integration by parts. We should be able to then pull you through.

Comment: Let's consider your integral is $I$. Now, try to solve $I^2$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: Added my work so far

Comment: @khashayer you'll still have to integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}t$ to write

$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt,$$

which by evenness of the integrand is

$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt,$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sqrt \pi }{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt\right),$$

and the expression inside parentheses is just the variance of a standard normal random variable, which is 1. Thus, the integral is $\sqrt \pi/4.$

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need now is to render

$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^2/2) dx.$

There are many ways to evaluate this [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). Clicking on the link should give you some ideas.